# Remove compiled package without the source files

Tags: software-installation, uninstall

As I can see from other questions, in order to remove a manually compiled package I need to use `make uninstall`. However, I deleted the source files, so I cannot do this. I [learned](https://superuser.com/questions/545721/where-should-i-store-source-downloads-for-installation) that in the future I need to use `checkinstall` rather than simply `install` when using `make`, so this problem disappears.

For my present situation, how do I remove the package that I compiled manually?

To provide context, the repository version of my distribution (xUbuntu 16.04) only has filezilla version 3.15, whereas I manually installed version 3.25. Now, I want to upgrade to version 3.31. Notice that [I am aware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7659/can-i-update-software-installed-from-source-code-directly) that I could simply try to install on top of the current version, but I still want to know how to delete packages without the source files.

Comment: You need to get the list of all the files added after the compilation and removing them manually.

Comment: You could restore the source files and attempt `make uninstall`

Comment: There is no standardization when it comes to `make install`. It is completely up to the software maintainer how they implement it. Thus this is why you should use package management. Otherwise your system is going to be littered with untracked files that can cause all sorts of nightmares.

Comment: @0xSheepdog So I could, for instance, reinstall the same version using the source files, and then uninstall with make?

Comment: I would do everything up to but NOT including `make install`.

Comment: and if the original source doesn't have a `make uninstall`, you can use `make -n install` and redirect to a file....then examine the file to get the list of filenames to remove.  Not using packages (or, at least, `stow` or `checkinstall`) makes a mess that is a major PITA to clean up. a pain to upgrade too.